# Where can I learn about mortality rates for 19th century American sailors?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, whaling

I would especially like to know the difference in survival rate for whalers versus merchant sailors in New England.

It seems to me that Melville discussed this in *Moby Dick* (which of course need not be a statistically accurate source), but I do not find such a passage now.